# PHPRunner Javascript API onload function

Tags: javascript, php, phprunner

I am facing an issue in adding the JS in the PHPRunner, I want to insert some JS function of Google Maps and have those function but not sure how to add the function in PHPRunner.

Can anyone help me in adding some Javascript in PHPRunner editor?

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? https://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/docs/how_to_add_external_files.htm

Comment: @imvain2 thanks for the reply. I don't want to add external file. I want to add it in the PHP javascript onload function